# How to change test run timeout?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xunit, visual-studio-mac

Some of my test classes take longer than a minute to run and I can't complete them because it cancels it saying:

> Canceling test run: test run timeout of 60000 milliseconds exceeded.

Is this configurable somewhere? I'm using the latest versions of:

- Visual Studio for Mac
- xunit
- xunit.runner.visualstudio
- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk

Comment: VSTest supports passing a [run settings file](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/configure.md) on the command line. This allows you to set a timeout. However I suspect that Visual Studio for Mac will need to be modified to support this. I believe it needs to be passed as a command line argument to the vstest runner which Visual Studio for Mac is not doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VS Test, which is used by Visual Studio for Mac to run the .NET Core Test project tests, supports passing a [run settings file](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/configure.md) on the command line. This allows you to set a timeout.

Looking at the [Visual Studio for Mac source code it seems this value of 60 seconds](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/9288325908994ab782b76171b8e2ca8c8af892bc/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest/VsTestAdapter.cs#L70) is unfortunately hard coded.

Visual Studio for Mac generates its own run settings which it passes to the VS Test runner.

You may want to report this on the [Visual Studio for Mac developer community forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/41/index.html) or open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/issues) so you can be notified when it gets fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will open an issue

Comment: Does anyone know if this has been fixed or if there's a workaround?

Comment: I added an issue [here](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/issues/3513). As far as I know, there is not a workaround.

Comment: Looks like this is fixed in the beta channel (via Karl Green's link). They updated it to set the timeout to the maximum possible value so essentially there is no longer a timeout.